# How to load an image from asp.net web api in angular 4?

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api2

I am uploading an image from angular 4 and storing it in a folder of my web api project. How to get those image from backend? This is the code for storing it in web api below.

```
[HttpPost]
    [Route("api/SaveFoodItemImage")]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public HttpResponseMessage SaveFoodItemImage()
    {
        string imageName = null;
        var httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;         
        var postedFile = httpRequest.Files["Image"];         
        imageName = new String(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(postedFile.FileName).Take(10).ToArray()).Replace(" ", "-");
        imageName = imageName + DateTime.Now.ToString("yymmssfff") + Path.GetExtension(postedFile.FileName);
        var filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Image/" + imageName);
        postedFile.SaveAs(filePath);
        var uploadedImageId = httpRequest["FoodItemId"];           
        var foodItem = _context.FoodItems.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == uploadedImageId);
        foodItem.FoodItemImage = imageName;
        _context.SaveChanges();
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created);
    }
```

How can I retrieve them in a object in frontend ?

Comment: Why not just point the "src" attribute to an api that fetches the image?

Comment: The src attribute just get the image name in front end. It displays the image name only, not the image

Comment: That doesn't make sense to me - maybe you could post a snippet of your HTML and angular code?

Comment: Okay. I'll do that after a while.